# Does an htaccess rewrite rule help prevent SQL Injection?

Tags: .htaccess, sql-injection

I have the following rule in htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/?$ test.php?&url=$1 [L]
```

My question is this:

If I have the following URL `http://www.example.com/this-is-a-title`

Is the `$url` variable subject to SQL injection, or should I not worry about it because the RewriteRule only allows letters, numbers, dashes and underscores and not quotes or apostrophes or + signs?

Edit:
Follow up question

What is happening if this is the url? `http://www.example.com/this'is"a+title`

When I place that in the url bar I get a  404 error, but what is actually happening. Are the symbols`' " +` being ignored or stripped or what exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always consider yourself vulnerable to SQL injection attack if you don't properly sanitize your data before placing it into a query. Using an `.htaccess` rewrite is not and should never be considered a practice to prevent SQL injection.

Use `mysql_real_escape_string` or `pg_escape_string` (if using PHP) or use prepared statements on all queries using variables from a `POST` or `GET`. Always.

Comment: Why is not acceptable? Under what conditions would an injection attack work with the above `.htaccess` rules? I don't disagree, I just would like to know why.

Comment: It would not be acceptable as your *only* line of defense. Security through obscurity should never be practiced. All it would take is one person to figure out the direct URL and exploit it. You should always, always, *always* sanitize data going into a database. **Always.**

Answer (score 1):

In theory, no the variable isn't subject to injection. However, you still ALWAYS should be sanitizing your inputs. It's simply best practice, because if someone manages to attack the server by another method, your .htaccess could be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

It depends from the script itself. You may be able to hex encode de input, like `0x2d3120756e696f6e2073656c656374202e2e2e2e`. If the script decodes it your .htaccess will fail to protect you.